# .htaccess redirect if file exists in subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following challenge. Assuming the following file is requested from the server:
/pages/subfolder/mypage.php

Is there an option using mod-rewrite to do the following:

> Look into a specific folder f. e. /USERMOD if the requested file (and structure) exists
>
> If Yes, execute this file with all parameters
>
> If Not, execute the requested file.

The background would be that the rewrite looks if there is a replacement under /USERMOD having the same folder structure. If an replacement exists use this one otherwise us the original file.

Actually (but doesn't work) I have is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/USERMOD/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/USERMOD/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /USERMOD/$1 [L]
```

Thanks for any hint and help!

EDIT: The full .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/USERMOD/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/USERMOD/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /USERMOD/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.(php|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)?/admin/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)?/images/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)?/templates/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

##boosted CONTENT
RewriteRule (.*/)?info/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.html.* shop_content.php?gm_boosted_content=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]

##boosted PRODUCTS
RewriteRule (.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.html product_info.php?gm_boosted_product=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]

##boosted CATEGORIES
RewriteRule (.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?.* index.php?gm_boosted_category=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that `.htaccess` can do this. If so, you might want to look at a PHP script that does this.

Comment: You rule should work. Do you have more rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: hey, thanks for the replies. Yes there are more, this is the first one in the sequence.

Comment: Other rules can cause conflict, can you paste full .htaccess in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have your initial rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^USERMOD/ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/USERMOD/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /USERMOD/$1 [L]

# rest of your rules come here
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying this on xampp actually but does not work. Requested URL is f. e. http://127.0.0.1/admin/orders.php?oID=400210&action=edit  --> file: http://127.0.0.1/USERMOD/admin/orders.php would exist but is not executed.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess? Is there any other .htaccess in `/admin/` folder also?

Comment: It's located in the root. And no other .htaccess in /admin/.

Comment: I just tested this rule on my localhost and it worked fine. Try to test with just these 2 rules in your .htaccess

Comment: Sorry for opening old topic again. Thank you, this really works. I just don't understand, how this is possible. How in `RewriteCond` it can check file `$1`, when I never assigned something into `$1`. I understand in `RewriteRule` is `$1` taken from regex `^(.*)$`, but RewriteCond is before that. Can you give me explanation please?
Thank you

Comment: Actually `RewriteCond` executes after pattern matching of `RewriteRule`